# ADO.Net Table-Valued Parameter (TVP): Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, table-valued-parameters

I am working with a TVP, and I am trying to pass a data table to the stored procedure as a TVP. When the command tries to `ExecuteNonQuery()`, it throws an error:

> Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int. The data for table-valued parameter "@tvpPermitWork" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.

I checked the data table using the visualizer, and I've found all of the data to be correct. I am now stuck and I don't have the time to change it to stored procedures with individual parameters.

Any suggestions on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what's happening without seeing your code, but as a quick guess, have you set `SqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured` , and `SqlParameter.TypeName = "YourTableType"` ?

If so, what does the generated T-SQL look like (you can see it with SQL Profiler)?

How is your table type declared? -- `CREATE TYPE YourTableType as TABLE ( ... )`

How is your stored procedure declared? -- `CREATE PROC ... @arg YourTableType READONLY ... AS ...`

How is your DataTable configured? It should include something like:

```
yourDataTable.Columns.Add("columnName", typeof(datetime2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rick. I did exactly that but the problem was the underlying table column changed but not the table variable which resulted in a mismatch.

Answer (score 8):

I've found the solution for this issue.

You need to check the matching columns' **order** in your TVP and C# code.

For example, if you have the TVP like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tvp_FinDocContract] AS TABLE(
    [column_1_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [column_2_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [column_3_Id] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Then the C# code for creating the TVP must be like this:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();

// The column order is very important
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column_1_Id", typeof (Guid)){AllowDBNull = false};
tvp.Columns.Add("column_2_Id", typeof (Guid));
tvp.Columns.Add("column_3_Id", typeof (DateTime));

foreach (var item in ...)
{
    //just populating
}
```

Comment: Been stuck on this for hours, thanks! As an aside, if you are generating datatable dynamically from an object, you can also order your properties by metadatatoken: 

(typeof(T).GetProperties().OrderBy(x=>x.MetadataToken)).ToArray(); 

This way the columns will be in the same order you have typed your class properties.

Comment: Just had this exact error and this was the solution for me.  Who would have guessed that column order was more important than column name for TVPs?

Answer (score 4):

It's SQL fault, table types insert without column in .NET. You should create your same order with your table type. As you can see on sample.

I spend two day for this.

```
declare @p1 dbo.typeSoftCopyDocument
insert into @p1 values(275,491196,N'000001.tif',1,100,5330900910,'2018-09-06 14:49:18',111111,N'xxx',N'xxxx')
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wasted more than an hour trying to figure out what's wrong with my datatypes. Order of columns never occurred to my mind :)

Comment: Wanted to add that if you're using a DataTable and your column setup order doesn't match the type, you'll encounter the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime it occurred if table valued parameter not passed as per SQL TVP column order.

It should have same ordering in  .NET & SQL

```
[id] [int] NULL,
[appStatus] [varchar](10) NULL,
[lodgedBy] [varchar](10) NULL,
```

.NET

```
objSearch = new AppSearchEN();
objSearch.id= context.Request["AppCat"].ToNullableInteger();
objSearch.appStatus= context.Request["AppStatus"] == "0" ? null : context.Request["AppStatus"];
objSearch.lodgedBy= context.Request["lodgedBy"] == "0" ? null : context.Request["lodgedBy"];
```

Then While passing parameter in .NET it must have same order of the parameter to table valued fn